# wget execute script after download

Tags: linux, bash, script, download, wget

I need every time you complete a transfer program wget this run a script.

this is my full command line:

```
wget -i urls-to-downloads.txt
```

My problem is that I want to go subtracting it downloads the total each time a transfer is completed. As you can see in my example is not a single file but are multiple files to download so I can not use pipe (|).

UPDATED:

I have urls-to-downloads.txt file with:

```
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/firefox/firefox-dbg_24.0+build1-0ubuntu0.13.04.1_amd64.deb
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/firefox/firefox-dbg_24.0+build1-0ubuntu0.13.04.1_i386.deb
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/t/thunderbird/thunderbird-dbg_24.0+build1-0ubuntu0.13.04.1_amd64.deb
```

And I need when download the first: `http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/firefox/firefox-dbg_24.0+build1-0ubuntu0.13.04.1_amd64.deb` execute a script, in this script I write a file, output, where I put the size. and so on (2 url and 3 url in this case)

The english not is my native lenguage.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do not understand what _go subtracting it downloads_ means, could you please clarify and explain what you want to do? Maybe you could also provide an example showing what you would do if there was only one url to download from.

Comment: @Tim: I updated my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could iterate over the urls outside `wget`.

For example the following `bash` `for` loop allows you to call your script after each file finishes downloading.

```
#!/bin/bash
for iurl in $(cat urls-to-downloads.txt); do
    wget $iurl && yourlogscript
done
```